# How to convert decimal to varchar with leading zero in DB2?

Tags: db2

I want to convert the result of a division to a character string in DB2.
My result when I do `'0.24'||'%'` is `'.24%'`
I don't understand how to get exactly the output `'0.24%'`

Answer (score 0):

hi try Something like this

```
 case when myval<1 and myval>0 then '0' || cast(myval as char(15))  
 when myval>-1 and myval<0 then '-0' || cast(abs(myval) as char(15))
 else cast(myval as char(15)) end myvaltochar
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My recent solution is the same with your's.
But I think it's just a temporary solution. 
If i don't use case when, Do you have another ways to solve my problem?
Tks so much.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
to_char( yourzone                                              
repeat('0', length(trim(int(abs(yourzone))))) || '.'||         
repeat('0', length(trim(                                       
INTEGER(SUBSTR(CHAR(-123.36),LOCATE(',',CHAR(yourzone))+1))))) 
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

`SELECT VARCHAR_FORMAT(24.0/100,'0.00')||'%'` ...

If you are dividing integer types, you'll have to cast them as `DOUBLE()` otherwise the result will be 0